# How to toggle in button using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am having a button when I click it becomes active but on another click, I want to remove active CSS

When I click on the button it becomes active by adding an active class to it. Here is what I tried, but what I was trying is when I click on the same buttons the active CSS should be removed, basically want to do toggle

```js
const myDemo = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.light')
  allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'))
  clickedElem.classList.add('active')
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `clickedElem.classList.toggle` to toggle the classes.

Before that, you need to remove the `active` class names except for the current selected button as follows.

```js
const myDemo = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target;
  console.log(clickedElem);
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.light');
  allBtns.forEach(btn => {
    if (clickedElem != btn) {
      btn.classList.remove('active');
    }
  });
  clickedElem.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
```

Or the other way, you can store the previous selected button and use it.

```js
let previousClicked = null;

const myDemo = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target;
  if (clickedElem === previousClicked) {
    clickedElem.classList.remove('active');
    return;
  }
  
  if (previousClicked != null) {
    previousClicked.classList.remove('active');
  }
  clickedElem.classList.add('active');
  previousClicked = clickedElem;
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Derek.W, I was looking for a multi-select option

Answer (score 0):

You can try using built-in toggle function in your "myDemo" function. Instead of  using remove(), just add this line:

```
btn.classList.toggle("active");
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `classList.toggle()`.

```js
const myDemo = (event) => {
  const clickedElem = event.target;
  const allBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn.light');

  // remove the class from all buttons
  allBtns.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));

  // reapply the class for the button that was clicked
  clickedElem.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
<button onclick="myDemo(event)" class="btn light">DOG</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in your function, you seem to want to also remove the `active` class from any other button else in the page. This is my approach:

```
let activeButton;

const selectButton = e => {
  if (activeButton) {
    activeButton.classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (activeButton === e.currentTarget) {
    activeButton = null;
    return;
  }

  e.currentTarget.classList.add('active');
  activeButton = e.currentTarget;
};
```

This way it does not have to loop though every buttons to deactive them, as it keeps track of the active button.